# Stuck on loading initial ramdisk after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I am running ubuntu 21.10 on a lenovo yoga 7i laptop. It has an issue with the speakers that is addressed in kernel `5.14.14` so I tried upgrading both to that version and `5.15.1`.
When I do, trying to boot normally results in a black screen, and launching either the recovery mode or the normal one through Aditional Options in grub just shows it stuck at the "`loading initial ramdisk`" message. The default kernel 5.13.20 works fine

Also, both my Ubuntu partition and windows partition are encrypted (LUKS and Bitlocker respectively)

I have seen often that disabling PTT and enabling legacy boot in the bios is supposed to work, but the Lenovo bios do not offer a legacy mode option as far as I can find it.
Anyone has ideas on how to diagnose/solve this issue?

Comment: What GPU ? If I can guess is intel =/
Got the same issue. With or without LUKS encryption, if I upgrade the kernel manually I got stuck at ar same point. Also got random freeze and only can force restart. Same as you there is no legacy mode in bios.
For now, around the web, this is a bug in the kernel that is reported to the kernel. And is happening to any Linux flavor. I try ubuntu, kali, parrot, and some others. 
I/We try to add an extra swap. nothing helps. Also if I book live USB same issue. Memetest pass 4/4.

Comment: @dMatija It is indeed an intel integrated GPU. Didn't realize it could be a kernel bug

Comment: For reason still unknown to me, all results that I encounter so far it is due to a bug in the kernel tied to the intel GPU. In my case CometLake ( mesa drivers not helping ) chip. 2nd laptop has intel + NVidia GPU. If I use intel it bugs again. on Nvidia all works perfectly.
I try to make changes around the kernel and things that as not make sense to change it. Just to prove my own common sense around this. 
When Linux is your main OS and use it for all daily work and in free time this can be extremely an issue. Hope this will be fixed soon.